# Lost wifi after 16.04 LTS upgrade (from Ubuntu 15.10)

Tags: networking, wireless, upgrade, 15.10, 16.04

I'm an Ubuntu newbie, i have an Acer Aspire ES1-520 . Everything was working fine until some days ago when i've accepted to upgrade to 16.04 LTS (64x). Now i cannot use wifi. Is there a way to come back to 15.10 (64x) easily, or to turn off the secure boot (may be it can solve as i read in another thread). How to see the bios panel? I am not a coder/programmer (i come from the windows world) so be patient. Is there a patch or something easy to make my wifi card work again. Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Lite-on Communications Inc BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [11ad:6645] 
Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: There is no easy way to downgrade Ubuntu to 15.10. You need to look into your laptop manual to see how to get into UEFI settings. It is not OS related. In many cases ESC button will do. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-dkms-modules-in-ubuntu-16 That may solve the issue easily if it is related to a 3rd party driver.

Comment: 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Lite-on Communications Inc BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [11ad:6645] 
Kernel modules: bcma, wl

Comment: I found the UEFI settings pressing F2. Do i need to choose the [LEGACY] Boot Mode instead the [UEFI]? actually there is the SECURE BOOT [ENABLED] 1: USB HDD 2: ubuntuST500LT012-1DG142 3: ATAPI CDROM 4: ... What can I do?

Comment: Not legacy. Just disable secure boot.

Comment: Solved!!! To DISABLE the Secure Boot in the UEFI settings it's necessary to SET SUPERVISOR PASSWORD in the SECURITY PANEL, ONLY after that is possible to disable the Secure Boot it in the BOOT PANEL. After that Ubuntu see the wifi card and everything works fine, thanks for your help Pilot6!!!

Answer (score 0):

Disable Secure Boot in UEFI settings, and the Wi-Fi should work.